# Merge data sets with different columns in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a data set in several sheets in Excel that I need to merge into one sheet. The problem is that the columns used are not identical, some are always used and some only in a few sheets. The location of the columns are not the same either, i.e. one column may have location X in one sheet and location Y in another sheet. How can I merge these into one sheet without losing data and structure?

Please see the attached for examples of column header. One row represents one sheet with data and its column headers

[image]

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create the final merged sheet with all the columns from all the sheets, arranged in any order. Then write this formula in cell B2.

```
=IFERROR(HLOOKUP(B$1,'My Sheet 1'!$A$1:$Z1001, ROW(A2),FALSE),"")
```

The formula will look for the column caption in your merged sheet in the column captions in a source sheet and extract the values from that column. If the column isn't found in the source sheet the formula will return a null string which appears as a blank. It follows that you can copy the formula left and right and all the way down without needing to change it.

1. `B$1` assumes the column caption in B1 of the merged sheet. You can change the location to another row. As you copy the formula to the right it will automatically adjust to C$1, D$1 etc.
2. `'My Sheet 1'` is the name of a source sheet. You will need to create different formulas to import from each of your source sheets.
3. `$A$1:$Z$1001` is the range to copy from. Make sure it has the maximum number of columns of any of your source sheets, and the maximum number of rows, too. Note that row 1 must contain the column captions. If the column captions in a source sheet are in another row, the lookup range must be adjusted to have that row at the top.
4. `ROW(A2)` returns the row number of A2 which is, of course, 2. It would be nice if the row number in the lookup range would be the same as the sheet row number but not necessarily so. The number specifies the 2nd row in the lookup range. Therefore, if the range is $A$3:$Z$1001 the cell in the second row in column B would be B4 but it would still be `ROW(A2)` in the formula. Of course, `ROW(A2)` changes as you copy left, right and down, and that ensures that it can retrieve all values.

However, after you have imported all 888 rows from one sheet you may wish to append the imports from the next sheet starting in row 889 of the merged sheet. The formula you put there must, of course, refer to the other sheet, and it must again specify `ROW(A2)` because you want the values in the second row of the next sheet in row 889 of the merged sheet. The adjusted formula is good for all imports from the second sheet and need only be changed again when you start on the 3rd.

Once the import has been completed and verified you should replace the formulas in the merged sheet with the imported values. Select the entire sheet by clicking on the little rectangle where the vertical and horizontal rulers meet at the top left, then click `Copy` (or press Ctl+C), Click on the ribbon's `Paste` button and select one of the three choices offered under "Paste Values".